# SCLAlertView - Focus on textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swift4

I have a SCLAlertView with a textfield inside it. How can I make that textfield become first responder so that when the alert view is shown, i can automatically start writing instead of clicking on the textfield first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After showing alert you can put this code at the end of function.

```
@IBAction func showEdit(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(showCloseButton: true)
    let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
    let txt = alert.addTextField("Enter your name")
    _ = alert.addButton("Show Name") {
        print("Text value: \(txt.text ?? "NA")")
    }
    _ = alert.showEdit(kInfoTitle, subTitle:kSubtitle)

    //Add this code in show function to set textfield as first responder 
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        txt.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

If you have more than one textfield than you have to set first textfield as first responder.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I don't know why I hadn't thought about it.